# MAC address filtering in D-Link Modem

Tags: filtering, mac-address, modem

I want to filter some MAC address to access internet with my D-Link modem.

modem's model: DSL-2730U

how can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to

> Advanced->Filtering Options->MAC Filter

and then

> add Filter